# Remove info lines at the end of a list

Tags: python

I've written this code

```
time=list()
for i in range(289):
   df = pd.read_csv('noname' + str(i+1) + '.csv', skiprows=[1,2])
   T=df.t
   time.append(T)
```

when I print the list it returns (I'm reporting just a slice)

```
72    00:12:10
73    00:12:20
74    00:12:30
75    00:12:40
76    00:12:50
Name: t, dtype: object, 0      00:00:00
1      00:00:02
2      00:00:04
3      00:00:06
4      00:00:09
5      00:00:11
6      00:00:13`
```

How can i remove the lines (there's one for every file that the code reads)  `Name: t, dtype: object` to have a list without interruption?

Comment: are you trying to create 289 data frames?

Comment: I'm trying to get the data from a single column of 289 csv and create a list containing them all. I'm new to python so i don't know if there's a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a `list` of 289 `pandas.Series`, which keep their indices

## DataFrame

When all csv-files are the same length, the easiest is to make 1 large `DataFrame`

```
no_files = 289

time =  pd.DataFrame(columns=range(no_files))

for i in range(289):
   df = pd.read_csv('noname' + str(i+1) + '.csv', skiprows=[1,2])
   time[i] = df.t
```

This also works if the lengths are not the same, but then you will get `NaN`s at the end of some columns

## list

```
list = []
for i in range(289):
   df = pd.read_csv('noname' + str(i+1) + '.csv', skiprows=[1,2])
   list.append(df.t.tolist())
```

Comment: I used the list method as I need a list and it worked, thanks very much!